# Why is it watson "Try it out" chat mapping the answer to Irrelevant?

Tags: watson-conversation

In my dialog flow I have an node triggered by an `#app_question` intent that answers with a question about a person's location - "Where's your location?", then, I've created a child node that is triggered by an entity `@app_location` inside of which I have `@app_location:americas`, `@app_location:other`.

Watson is answering correctly in the Try it out chat, when I say I'm in america, it outputs the correct answer, but "Irrelevant" appears in the node box. Should I worry about that, is that standard or I am doing something wrong?

ps: I was using Jump to, but received an error. If I'm supposed to use Jump To, I can copy and paste the error here.

Below are screenshots:

[image: dialog flow]

[image: try it out - irrelevant mapping]

If anyone can help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Conversation will always try to determine what the intent is, even if you are not interested in it at that time. The try it out is just showing you what it tried to figure out what the intent was. Not that it would do anything with it.

As you are looking for an entity and not an intent it should be fine.

Comment: Great! I will continue to build the Dialog.
Thanks a lot, Simon :)